# Install Qt5.8 libraries on Ubuntu 14 x86_64

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run a program which needs Qt5.8 libraries, and the underlying OS is Ubuntu 14.05.5 LTS

This OS seems to include a prebuilt package for Qt 5.2.1 and nothing later in the repos.

Can I safely add Qt5.8 libraries? How would I do so?  (I can only find instructions for installing the full Qt IDE)

Comment: You can refer to [Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) to determine what libs your specific app requires and ship them along with the app

Comment: The author can't ship Qt libraries with the app since that violates the Qt license.  I need to install Qt 5.8 separately

Comment: You can install Qt 5.8 onto Ubuntu Trusty from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt58-trusty). There are [more](https://launchpad.net/~beineri) Qt PPAs available for various Ubuntu editions, just in case.

Comment: Dmitry - that's exactly what I needed thanks.  (I'd click answered for that)

Comment: "The author can't ship Qt libraries with the app since that violates the Qt license." that's almost certainly incorrect.